# Is there any JavaFX property wrapper for bidirectional binding?

Tags: java, javafx, properties, wrapper, bidirectional

I am looking for the function which helps me map a POJO. I have been looking into the `JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder` and also beanpath

However it does not achieve my goal. I would like to wrap a pojo method into a JavaFX objectproperty for usage in bidirectional binding.

The goal is a property for usagen in a binding so the instance of `Xyz` gets updated for the specifiedd languageCode when a user edits the `TextField`.

```
public class Xyz {
    private Map<String,String> multilingualTitles = ...;

    public String getTitleFor( String languageCode ) { /* abbreviated */ }
    public void setTitleFor( String languageCode, String title ) { /* abbreviated */ }
}

public void bindtoTextField( Xyz theObject, javafx.scene.control.TextField textField )
{
    final String languageCode = "EN"; // or class field

    /* 
     * Is there something that does what is below?
     */ 
    Property<String> prop = **TheThingIamLookingFor**.create( theObject, 
        (i) -> i.getTitleFor( languageCode ),
        (i,nv) -> i.setTitleFor( languageCode, nv ) )


    textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional( prop );
}
```

The additional reason for the wrapper property (`prop`) is that I want to reuse the instantiated property for preview and combined bindings in another binding

Comment: Maybe explain what it is you want to achieve. Something like "when the user types into the text field I want... to happen" or "I want to add a functionality to my object that give... does...". I don't understand what your pseudo-code is supposed to do.

Comment: I added some explanation in the above post. The idea is when updating the textfield the instanceof Xyz gets updated.

Comment: The instance should be updated in what way? Add a text example.